# Android Databinding error - error: cannot find symbol @Nullable DataBindingComponent component

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I am using android studio: 3.2.1  enabled data-binding in gradle files

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

android gradle: 3.3.0

everything works fine in debug variant but in release variant getting following error.

error: cannot find symbol

```
     @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have included all the jar's while exporting Release APK.